# Exclude parent and its children or modules in maven command executing lifecycle

Tags: maven, maven-3

Executing `mvn clean install -pl !Parent2` does **NOT** apply life-cycles on `Parent2` children's nor modules. While all sub-projects are in same level I try to combine `Project2` & `Project2` into one parent `Parent2` to exclude it only from many life-cycles. **How could this be done ?**

**Similarly** `mvn clean install -pl Parent2` only applied on `Parent2` without its children/modules !!

[image]

Here are the latest POMs I reached to structure. Noting that my only restriction is keeping folders of all in same level (under `Parent1`)

**Parent1**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>any</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
    <version>whatever</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>Parent2</module>
    <module>Project1</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

**Parent2**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>any</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
        <version>whatever</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <artifactId>Parent2</artifactId>
<modules>
    <module>../Project2</module>
    <module>../Project3</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

**Project1**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>any</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
        <version>whatever</version>
    </parent>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
</project>
```

**Project2 (Project3 is exactly the same)**

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>any</groupId>
        <artifactId>Parent2</artifactId>
        <version>whatever</version>
        <relativePath>../Parent2</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
</project>
```

Comment: I'm interested in this as well, running `mvn clean -pl !Parent2` only cleans `Parent2` project which is POM and not its children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm interested in applying the exclusion on sub-modules as well. However `mvn clean install -pl Parent2 -amd` works as wanted & expected applying `clean` & `install` into `Parent2`, `Project2` & `Project3`. However, as pointed by [Pawl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180235/pawel)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326247/exclude-parent-and-its-children-or-modules-in-maven-command-executing-lifecycle#comment95489157_54335053) and according to [MNG-5230](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230) issue

> Nested modules are not excluded by parent module. The exclusion method mimics the inclusion method and its matcher does not support wildcards etc. So to cascade exclusion would necessitate an extra flag like `-amd`.
>
> The dependency graph is filtered in the following order when using
>   -pl:
>   1. included projects + possibly upstream and downstream
>   2. excluded projects
>   3. skipping for resume projects
>
> So it should be possible to directly exclude nested modules as they should be present in the intial dependency graph before filtering starts.

So excluding nested modules using their parent/holder `pom` is not possible. Here is how I worked around it to solve this. Simply using profiles and completely removing sub-modules outside profiles definition solved it.

**In short** is using profiles to identify modules with noting that modules identified outside profiles are shared no matter what profile is activated

**Example** as of OP projects naming followed

**Parent1** (Added `Project4` as same as `Project1` just for clarifying)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>multi-modules-profile</id>
        <modules>
            <module>Parent2</module>
            <module>Project2</module>
            <module>Project3</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>simple-module-profile</id>
        <modules>
            <module>Project1</module>
        </modules>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<modules>
    <module>Project4</module>
</modules>
```

**Project1** (& `Project4` is similar)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
```

**Parent2**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>Parent2</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**Project2** (& `Project3` is similar)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Parent2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../Parent2</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
```

Now running `mvn clean` would apply on `Parent1`, `Project1` & `Project4` because `Project1` is in profile that is activated by default (without specifying profile during the execution). This has same effect running `mvn clean -P simple-module-profile` because `Project4` is shared outside profiles definitions.

Finally, running `mvn clean -P multi-modules-profile` will be  applied to `Parent1`, `Project4`, `Parent2`, `Project2` & `Project3` leaving `Project1` out which is desired. Notice `Project4` is always in because it's outside profiles definitions.

Comment: OK that did the trick. Seems profiles in maven should be used greatly for separating working modules at a given time. I'll mark this answer as solved for now since it did answer the core question. At least until a modification or update is done for another option than profiles

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the answer applies only to:

> Similarly mvn clean install -pl Parent2 only applied on Parent2 without its children/modules !!

Use `mvn -pl Parent2 -amd clean install` to build Parent2 and all of it's modules.

See the reference: https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html#_making_project_dependents

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't that clear, the first command I typed is `mvn clean install -pl !Parent2` which excludes the module `Parent2` ONLY without its children nor modules which is NOT the desired behavior. I tried with `-amd` & `-am` but still only the `Parent2` pom project is excluded while the children are NOT.

Comment: Thx, fixed answer to be partial.

Comment: Check https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5230 seems like original author of exclusion syntax for `-pl` option was interested in exclusion of nested modules (last comment). Maybe it'll pay off to contact him about that.